# Change message header in Java box with "if" and "else"

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

How do I change the message header in a showMessageDialog if I have several strings and integers working together?

This is how I can make it work:

```
showMessageDialog (null, "string", "where I change the name of the box", INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

This is where I can't make it work:

```
if (price >= 300) {
    deduction = price * 0.10;
    price = price - deduction;

    showMessageDialog (null, "Total price: ", 
                "where I want to change the        name", INFORMATION_MESSAGE 
                + price + " ." + " Received deduction: " + deduction);
```

Eclipse gives the following error message:

> "The method showMessageDialog (Component, Object, String, int) in the
>   type JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (null, String,
>   String, String)" and suggests that I create method  showMessageDialog
>   (Object, String, String, String).

Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INFORMATION_MESSAGE is a constant that defines the message type. Try using this way instead:

```
showMessageDialog(null, "Total price: ", price + " ." + " Received deduction: " + deduction, INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't really say I understand the question, though try..

```
showMessageDialog (null, "Total price: " + 
    + price + " ." + " Received deduction: " + deduction,
    "where I want to change the name", INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```